# Error - while running npm run setup in angular4

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am trying to use ng2 date-time picker. I have the source code from -

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetimepicker. 
But the difficulty here is the Error that comes while implementing its style .

```
ERROR in ./app/master-system/transaction/transaction.component.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../node_modules/ngx-datetime- 
picker/ngx-datetimepicker/src/assets/ngx-datetime-picker.css' in 
'/home/dell/Downloads/Datshare/Adaani5.0 (another 
copy).0/src/app/master-system/transaction'.
```

So i believe thats because i have to run (please tell me if i am wrong here) the Development: Work flow. But then i am getting this error

> npm ERR! missing script: setup

Please help .

Comment: If you just use this as a lib, you don't need to run `setup` since it is a script for **developing ng2-datetimepicker**.

Comment: you mean - that i include it in index.html file like this - <script src = 
   "https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetimepicker"></script>

Comment: Guess you are trying to install this library, use `npm install ng2-datetimepicker` instead.

Comment: You can try to copy manually the css file as discussed here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-datetimepicker And see what you can get.

Comment: @ Pengyy...  i have done npm install ng2-datetimepicker. But getting the warning message -->npm WARN @angular/cdk@5.2.5 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=5.0.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

Comment: @HDJEMAI .. how to open the file to manually copy it. They have just  given the link

Comment: ignore the warnings the library is installed correctly normally it should work. to start the dev process run `ng serve`